# Tomcat console log to a file

Tags: java, tomcat, logging, securitymanager

Im using **Apache Tomcat 7**. When I'm **running Tomcat with security manager and with the `-Djava.security.debug` parameter** I'm getting so much of text in console. I can't read the text in console. So I need  the **console log into some file**. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Take a look in `C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Apache Tomcat 7....\logs` - you may find `localhost...log`.

Answer (score 7):

Remove `ConsoleHandler` from logging configuration. In `conf/logging.properties`:

Change this -

```
.handlers = 1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler, java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler
```

To this -

```
.handlers = 1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler
```

The logs will be in the file `catalina.log`.

---

If you want to disable console logging for selected applications, you can set `swallowOutput` in true in the `<Context>` element.

```
...
<Context path="..." swallowOutput="true"> 
...
```

Comment: it doesn't affected to me in apache-tomcat-7.0.5\logs\catalina.2014-10-14.log

Answer (score 3):

Using `catalina.bat` run can start the tomcat in the current console instead of a new console , so you can redirect all the standard error and standard output stream of this command to a file using

```
catalina.bat run > tomcat.log
```

Comment: where i have to put this cmd

Comment: @Hariprasath yes on cmd

Comment: but the cmd prompt doesnt run, it stucks after enter this cmd

Comment: @Hariprasath it does not struck, it will not print anything on console now, everything will be printed to a `tomcat.log` file, seaarch for that file.

Comment: yes thankyou. It logged in tomcat.log, but i need to run tomcat with some parameters like startup.bat -security. How can i.

Answer (score 1):

for ubuntu user, use following command:

1. cd /opt/apache-tomcat-8.0.36/bin$
2. ./catalina.sh run > tomcat.log

you will get the logs. Once you run this command you will get all the log files under /opt/apache-tomcat-8.0.36/logs folder..