# How to see tomcat console when tomcat started from services

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat

This might be silly question but I really don't know it.

I have performed some changes in my web application in java/jsp.
Tested it in localhost in eclipse where I can see logs in console.
After that I have deployed the changes to beta server and its not
reflecting as in localhost hence want to see running logs through
tomcat console but Tomcat is already running and was started with
services utility of windows.

Is there any way to open console of running tomcat.

I do know that we can see tomcat logs as well, but running console
will be preferred for me as there are multiple projects are running on
same server.

Comment: Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26359894 helps?

Answer (score 0):

You can check log file(s) in the tomcat-home/logs folder.

Answer (score 0):

You can attach Eclipse to a running process if you have started the server with the right settings:  see [Attach debugger to application using Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6855520/attach-debugger-to-application-using-eclipse)  On windows, you can either delete and reinstall the services as in https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/windows-service-howto.html or, you can add these parameters in the Windows registry for the Tomcat you are running:  see http://www.tomcatexpert.com/knowledge-base/allocating-more-ram-tomcat-windows .  I would be very careful with the registry hack unless you've hacked the registry before and are comfortable doing it.