# Where to see "console output" from Servlet when in Tomcat?

Tags: tomcat, servlets

I had a JavaSE app with main() method. I need to run it in a cloud. A good choice is Jelastic. So I converted my project to Dynamic Web project (Project Facets in Eclipse), created a ServletContextListener and put all my code from main() in that Servlet contextInitialized() method. My code has System.out.println and logging (slf4j) statements - In my Eclipse IDE I see all that output in console view. But as I deploy the project in Tomcat in the cloud - I am totally lost where too look for console output. I guess it is somewhere in the logs, but I cannot find those logs...

Comment: What cloud provider?  What operating system?  Do you have access to the machine (i.e. via ssh or remote desktop)?

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for tomcat logs in Jelastic then just hover on the application server and press "Log" button.

[image: Tomcat Logs in Jelastic]

Answer (score 0):

Tomcat doesn't redirect the console logs to a file, to do that you need to use logging tools like [log4j](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/) for example, or once you start your tomcat you can redirect the output to a file check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26359894/tomcat-console-log-to-a-file) and [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/252934/how-to-redirect-tomcat-console-log-to-files-tomcat-started-via-windows-bat) for more information.